# NuGet Restore from Batch Script

Tags: batch-file, msbuild, nuget

I wrote a quick batch script to build several solutions in order, however it currently doesn't restore NuGet packages so if I just downloaded the code onto a different machine it doesn't work without opening and restoring.  I'm trying to update the script to run a restore but something isn't working.  I am just using the line `call nuget restore path\to\solution.sln` but I'm getting errors.  Here is the output:

```
C:\Users\sfaust\Source\Repos\BIT>call nuget restore ModelChecker\ModelChecker.sln
MSBuild auto-detection: using msbuild version '16.4.0.56107' from 'C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Community\MSBuild\Current\bin'.
C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Community\MSBuild\Current\bin\Microsoft.Common.CurrentVersion.targets(359,25): error MSB4184: The expression "[MSBuild]::NormalizePath(C:\Users\sfaust\Source\Repos\BIT\ModelChecker\MCCore, obj\"Any CPU"\Debug\, MCCore.csproj.CopyComplete)" cannot be evaluated. Illegal characters in path. [C:\Users\sfaust\Source\Repos\BIT\ModelChecker\MCCore\MCCore.csproj]
C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Community\MSBuild\Current\bin\Microsoft.Common.CurrentVersion.targets(359,25): error MSB4184: The expression "[MSBuild]::NormalizePath(C:\Users\sfaust\Source\Repos\BIT\ModelChecker\MCConfigurator, obj\"Any CPU"\Debug\, MCConfigurator.csproj.CopyComplete)" cannot be evaluated. Illegal characters in path. [C:\Users\sfaust\Source\Repos\BIT\ModelChecker\MCConfigurator\MCConfigurator.csproj]
C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Community\MSBuild\Current\bin\Microsoft.Common.CurrentVersion.targets(359,25): error MSB4184: The expression "[MSBuild]::NormalizePath(C:\Users\sfaust\Source\Repos\BIT\ModelChecker\RMCApp, obj\"Any CPU"\Debug\, RMCApp.csproj.CopyComplete)" cannot be evaluated. Illegal characters in path. [C:\Users\sfaust\Source\Repos\BIT\ModelChecker\RMCApp\RMCApp.csproj]
C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Community\MSBuild\Current\bin\Microsoft.Common.CurrentVersion.targets(359,25): error MSB4184: The expression "[MSBuild]::NormalizePath(C:\Users\sfaust\Source\Repos\BIT\ModelChecker\MCCore_Tests, obj\"Any CPU"\Debug\, MCCore_Tests.csproj.CopyComplete)" cannot be evaluated. Illegal characters in path. [C:\Users\sfaust\Source\Repos\BIT\ModelChecker\MCCore_Tests\MCCore_Tests.csproj]
C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Community\MSBuild\Current\bin\Microsoft.Common.CurrentVersion.targets(359,25): error MSB4184: The expression "[MSBuild]::NormalizePath(C:\Users\sfaust\Source\Repos\BIT\ModelChecker\TestProject, obj\"Any CPU"\Debug\, TestProject.csproj.CopyComplete)" cannot be evaluated. Illegal characters in path. [C:\Users\sfaust\Source\Repos\BIT\ModelChecker\TestProject\TestProject.csproj]

WARNING: Error reading msbuild project information, ensure that your input solution or project file is valid. NETCore and UAP projects will be skipped, only packages.config files will be restored.
All packages listed in packages.config are already installed.
```

Based on the last line it kind of seems like it worked but the other errors kind of seem like it didn't...  What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: Plain and simple.  This is a Windows limitation. You cannot have double quotes in your path.

Comment: Hm, didn't seem to work.  I took the quotes out of my call (see updated question) but it still gives the same thing...

Comment: Not that path.  It should be pretty darn clear from the Error message.  You have quotes in this path!  `error MSB4184: The expression "[MSBuild]::NormalizePath(C:\Users\sfaust\Source\Repos\BIT\ModelChecker\MCCore, obj\"Any CPU"\Debug\, MCCore.csproj.CopyComplete)" cannot be evaluated. Illegal characters in path.`

Comment: Where is that path coming from though?  I'm sorry I don't understand, the only path I put in is the relative path to the script directory...  I don't see it in my .csproj file either.  It seems to be putting in build information (and the obj folder path?) but I don't know why.

Answer (score 1):

Ok after trying to reduce it to a minimal reproducible example I found the issue though I'm still not sure I fully understand why it's behaving this way.  I commented out everything that wasn't directly related to NuGet which was really just variable declarations... and it started working.  After that I put them back one at a time and narrowed it down to the line:

```
set platform="Any CPU"
```

That is just a place to declare the platform for the builds performed after the declaration so I didn't think it would have any effect since the variable wasn't used anywhere, but obviously it did since commenting it out fixed it and putting it back broke it again.

I ended up changing the variable name to `buildPlatform` instead of just `platform` and it fixed it so it is now restoring properly with no errors.

All I can think is that somehow it's using the batch script variables inside the .csproj files and doing some type of replacement to get that strange path.  Looking inside the .csproj file, though, I don't see how that would happen.  There are a couple uses of `$(Platform)` but they are conditions for build properties, they don't have anything to do with paths and replacing them would work just fine...  So I'm not sure why but that seems to be the solution.

If anyone can post a more complete answer with explanation of why this is I will gladly accept your answer over mine.

Comment: use this syntax: `set "platform=Any CPU"` (note the position of the quotes) to not include the quotes into the value. That should fix the "cannot be evaluated" errors. (After renaming the variable, `%platform%` is not defined (empty), so there are no "evil" quotes anymore)

Comment: Ok good to know thank you!  Do you know why it ended up that way though?  why would it do a replacement in the csproj file?

Comment: sorry, I'm quite confident in batch but I know literally nothing about that "nuget" stuff. Obviously something uses this variable to build the foldername. What? Why? How? - I don't have the slightest idea.